# JavaScript fetch api: TypeError failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, typeerror, fetch-api

I'm creating a blog with a friend as a small project between us.
I'm and tested the backend in PHP, he's writing the frontend code.
As he is still newer than me HTML and JS, I'm also writing the JS code to handle comms with the backend.
The issue we're facing and can't get our heads around is the following:
Logging in is possible with username or email and the password.
The login code works when

1. Username - password with curl
2. Email - password with curl
3. Username - password with Postman
4. Email - password with Postman
5. Username - password with vanilla JS fetch

What doesn't work is the Email - password with vanilla JS fetch. In this case we get the TypeError: Load failed or Failed to fetch.
This is the JS code:

```
    
        const credential = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        const body = JSON.stringify({ credential, password });
    
            fetch('/api/auth/login', { method: 'POST', body: body, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' } })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.access_token) {
                        localStorage.setItem('fit_token', data.access_token);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
```

The catch isn't even reached, nothing gets logged in console. I only see the error when I debug...

Can anyone point us in the right direction?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab in the developer tools? Do you see the network request? Also, add logging to the successful case. From what I can see, it's not clear if your code even fails. Also, where do you see the error exactly and is that the complete error message?

Comment: Check the `network` tab in your browser's developer tools. You will be able to see the request as well as the status and data it returned.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. There's nothing in the Network tab from the fetch, no call to the API. I can only see the errors when in debug mode and yes, that's the complete error message.